# How to match only numbers in a sentence

Tags: javascript

Using Flickr API.

```
result.items[i].published
```

Results in something like this 2012-12-21T14:36:24Z - notice the T and the Z?
How do I match only the numbers in 2012-12-21T14:36:24Z?

This is how it looks.

```
newPic.innerHTML = "<div class='pic-container'> <p class='title'>" + result.items[i].title + "</p> <a href="+ result.items[i].link +" >  <img src=\'" + result.items[i].media.m + "\'> </a></div><p class='author'>" +  result.items[i].author.match(/\(([^)]*)\)/)[1] + "</p><p class='published'>" + result.items[i].published + "</p>";
```

Comment: Can you give us more detail into what are you trying to achieve ? i'm not sure what answer to provide based on this. are you trying to print the date without T and Z? or something else ?

Comment: `new Date(result.items[i].published)` - then you should be able to take out the fields?

Comment: @Aviatrix Exactly! I'm trying to print the date without the T and Z.
You can have a look at it at www.johancarleborn.se to se what I mean if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RegExp matcher "\d" for this but I think a better solution would be to parse the Date with

```
var d = new Date(result.items[i].published)
```

From that you get a proper [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple regular expression like:

```
result.items[i].published.replace(/[a-z]/i , "");
```

or if you want to replace letters with spaces:

```
result.items[i].published.replace(/[a-z]/i , " ");
```

the two examples I provided will match ANY letter in your string and replace them, if you want to match more chars than just letters you can simply modify the regular expression.

Hope this answers your question,

Ignazio

Answer (score 0):

Because the JS date object is hell to work with , the best solution is to run a simple REGEX replace to the string.

`result.items[i].published.replace(/Z|T/gi," ")`

If you need to work and do some advanced stuff with date i recommend to you the [dateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) library.